# Value name of select option used as number in function

Tags: jquery

I'm selling 1-2 pieces of apples or oranges in a drop-down list. The value of the items has to be 'apple' and 'oranges' -- so how can I use the parsed names as numbers to count the cost?

```
<label>Which Fruit?</label>

<select class="buy" id="fruit">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="apple">Apple $1</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange $2</option>
</select>

<label>How Many?</label>

<select class="buy" id="amount">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="total" readonly="true">

$('.buy').on('change', function() {
    var fruit = parseInt($('#fruit').val());
    var amount = parseInt($('#amount').val());
    var total = fruit * amount;
    if(isNaN(total))
        $('#total').val('');
    else
        $('#total').val('$' + total);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/91Lk7oqo/

Comment: @chippa, change your how many to some different class otherwise code is executing each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fruit = 0;
var amount = 0;
$('.buy').on('change', function() {
if($(this).attr("id")=="fruit"){
       var selectedValue = $(this).val()+"";
       console.log(selectedValue);
       switch (selectedValue){
            case "apple":
              fruit = 1; <!-- or whatever value you want -->
              break;
            case "orange":
              fruit = 2;
              break;
            default:
              fruit = 0;
      }
}else if($(this).attr("id")=="amount"){
amount = parseInt($('#amount').val());
}
console.log(fruit)
console.log(amount)
var total = fruit * amount;
if(total == 0){
$('#total').val('');
} else{
$('#total').val('$' + total);
}
});
```

this works for sure i test it

Comment: works great, much obliged! here's the final working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91Lk7oqo/2/

Comment: sorry for multiple answers

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use switch case like:

```
var parsedValue = 0;
switch value{
   case "Apple":
      parsedValue = 1;
...
}
```

Comment: would you mind giving an example based on my code? thanks!

Comment: would you mind i add another answer? because in comment it is little bit hard to explain

Comment: that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Which Fruit?</label>

<select class="buy" id="fruit">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="apple">Apple $1</option>
<option value="orange">Orange $2</option>
</select>

<label>How Many?</label>

<select class="buy" id="amount">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="total" readonly="true">
<script>
    var fruit = 0;
    $('.buy').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).attr("id")=="fruit"){
           var selectedValue = $(this).val();
           switch (selectedValue){
                case "apple":
                  fruit = 1; <!-- or whatever value you want -->
                case "orange":
                  fruit = 2;
                default:
                  fruit = 0;
          }
    }
    var amount = parseInt($('#amount').val());
    var total = fruit * amount;
    if(total == 0){
    $('#total').val('');
    } else{
    $('#total').val('$' + total);
    }
    });
<script>
```

Comment: hmm -- running this on jsffidle doesn't work? the input field stays blank.
https://jsfiddle.net/91Lk7oqo/1/

Comment: check below answer :))) ... it works i test it ... its only the js section